# batch script get service status

Tags: batch-file

On w7 I want to receive the status of a service using psservice, since I want to do this on a remote computer later.

I try to get the batch script working on local machine first.

I have two issues: First issue is that "D:/PsService.exe query Server" will query ALL serviced containing the name "Server". I only want to query one specific service (in this example named "Server".

The other, bigger issue, is that my batch script are not working at all. It just "dies" (the CMD window immediately closes without execute the pause command, which make it extremely hard to debug).

I want to store the status of the service in a variable, which I gonna use later to compare example (IF %Status% EQ "RUNNING").

My code so far:

```
FOR /F token=3 %%i IN ('D:/PsService.exe query Server 2> NUL | find /I "STATE"') DO   ( SET Status=%%i )
echo %Status%
pause
```

Why does the CMD just die and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `pause` you could use `set /p myvariable=Terminate this script [y|n]?:` to wait for user input. You could make your live a lot easier using PowerShell.

Comment: To see why it dies, you should open a cmd window and start your batch there. Btw it's a syntax error in the for loop. You need to escape the redirection and also the pipe.

Comment: In batch, you escape using the carat, ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following will work for you

```
   @ECho off
   for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('D:/PsService.exe query "SERVICE" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do echo %%H
```

Comment: It works! that solved the biggest issue. You don´t happen to know how to query one and only one service? Trying D:/PsService.exe query "Server" I still query all services that begin on "Server" while I only want to query the specific service (in my example) named "Service" (and nothing more).

Comment: Hi, By mistake i type server in my code just replace server by "Service". and I hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

```
echo off
set /P srvname="Enter the servername  :"
echo %srvname%
set /P srvice="Enter the Service name :"
echo %srvice%
psservice.exe \\%srvname% query  %srvice% >a.txt
a.txt

pause
```