# Bat file to query service status with options

Tags: batch-file

I have this query to check the status of a service and give options based on that status but I am having some issues in the error portion. IT only seems to work of there is not an option chosen. Even then it only works the first time. AS you can see I have 3 options but if i select option 4 it defaults to option 1. PLease take a look and explain what I am missing.

```
    @echo off

ECHO Status of MGT System Manager Service

Goto Welcome

ECHO.



:Welcome

sc query MGTSM | findstr /i "STATE"

ECHO What would you like to do?


ECHO 1. Start Service

ECHO 2. Stop Service

ECHO 3. Exit

set /p choice=Select your choice.

if '%choice%'=='' ECHO "%choice%" is not valid please try again. 

if '%choice%'=='1' goto Start Service

if '%choice%'=='2' goto Stop Service

if '%choice%'=='3' goto Exit

ECHO.



:Start Service

net start MGTSM

goto Welcome





:Stop Service

net stop MGTSM

goto Welcome



:Exit

exit
```

Comment: "I am trying" implies that you've made an effort to do so. Can you [edit] your question to show your effort to do this yourself? Also, did you see [batch script get service status](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14944960) before posting here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285086/check-state-of-multiple-services-in-batch/24285853#24285853. Type `choice /?` for user input.

Comment: I did edit it with my first issue not being able to query the service properly.

Comment: Choice restricts entries to what you specify. Type in a command prompt `choice /c 123 /m "Enter Options"`. Computer beeps if 4 entered.

Answer (score 0):

`set /p` does not touch the variable, if you enter nothing (just ENTER). Therefore you should delete the variable before:

```
:Welcome
....
set "choice="      //this deletes %choice%
set /p "choice=Select your choice: "
if '%choice%'=='1' goto StartService
if '%choice%'=='2' goto StopService
if '%choice%'=='3' goto Exit
REM this line is only reached, when all of the "IF ... GOTO"  above failed
echo not valid input: "%choice%"
goto welcome       
...
```

Labels and `goto` have a problem with spaces: `goto start service` will go to "start", ignoring "service". Same with Labels: `:Start Service`, the Label is `:Start`, the "Service" is ignored.